# Trying to get next alarm time with "getNextAlarmClock()" but doesn't get the right answer

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I would like to show the next alarm set in a widget, so I am trying to get the next alarm time of an alarm I just have set on my phone at 15:30h

I am using the code:

```
    String nextAlarm = "";
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        try {
            assert alarmManager != null;
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo aci = alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock();
            nextAlarm = aci.toString();
             Log.w("nextAlarm ", aci.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  else {
        nextAlarm = Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED;
    }
```

This returns the nextAlarm string
 in logcat: `W/nextAlarm: android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo@4e0bf32`
running on SdkVersion 29

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the time, use `aci.getTriggerTime()` instead of `aci.toString()`. `AlarmClockInfo::getTriggerTime` returns the timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: @ huytc Thank you very much, been searching for days. This works Great `nextAlarm = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM HH:mm").format(new Date(aci.getTriggerTime()));`